# aws sstables stored in s3 to athena using glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Little disclaimer I've never used aws glue.

I have some sstables stored in s3 that I need to transfer to parquet.
I started a new job in glue from a blank graph, and when I chose the source as s3 with the bucket containing all the sstables, it looks like it accepts only specific data type. (json, csv and parquet)

I need to run a java code in order to dump the sstables to parquet using aws service (preferably glue) is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

since I cant upload files here, a link to a repo with sstable files:
https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools/tree/master/src/test/resources
the dump is only on one file `<str>-<int>-big-Data.db` but it need the rest of the files for the dump to work:

```
CompressionInfo.db
Filter.db
Index.db
Statistics.db
Summary.db
TOC.txt
```

Comment: Have you tried crawling these sstables using Glue crawler to see if it detects metadata? Can you attach a sample SStable to your question?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I'm afraid it does not work because you need 8 files to use the dump I added link to repo that contains those sstables

Comment: You cannot directly load these files to S3 in the form of parquet, Glue will not support it. You need to first convert them to JSON/CSV then convert them to parquet using Glue.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Is there a way to to do so maybe not in parquet?
I just need to use the dump on these files then transforming the json to csv can be done in glue

Comment: From which database did you exported these .db files from ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Cassandra

Comment: Have you tried exporting these tables in JSON format and the use Glue to convert to parquet file format https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/sstable/sstabledump.html ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy thats exactly what i want to do but i want to do it using an aws service . Is there any way of doing so?
I dont want to have to download all of those files use the sstabledump and then upload them again I want to do it using only aws services.

Comment: you should try EMR Spark then. check https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-better-deployments-of-spark-batch-jobs-to-aws-emr-using-apache-livy-adc2417f0d8b

Comment: Ok thanks ill check it out!